# MultiLanguage application - what would you use?

Tags: php, mysql

Would you rather use mySQL database to store language variables or php variables?

Please consider

- Performance
- Adding
- Editing

and how would you do it? Store it to php variables, for example

```
$language['en']["hello"] = "Hello";
$language['cz']["hello"] = "Ahoj";
```

and use function

```
function l($lvar)
{
    global $language, $default_language;
    return $language[$default_language][$lvar];
}
```

and use it like

```
<div id="test">
    <?php echo l("hello"); ?>
</div>
```

? What is better?

And what about to store them in database and every time (or once 10 minutes) create (generate) php file with variables

Comment: It depends on your use case. Who is going to have to edit those files? Will they need a web interface?

Comment: take Facebook as example - they do have tool for everyone to translate it and then add/edit votes on best translation

Comment: I would go with a XML file myself as it's not too hard to make a little UI for which can maintain the languages, using DB is (in my opinion) unnecessary load..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on some things:

1. Do you want [persistence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_%28computer_science%29) (e.g. do you want the variables to be stored once, and then retrieved)?

   If you want peristence then you should go with MySQL (or some XML/YAML file), to store up your data, so that even if you edit your code  in someway or migrate to another language it is not lost.
2. Do you want easy editing?
   If you save your data in a php file, external editing can be hard as you either have to rewrite that file or you have to someway save the newer changes. It is easier to change something store in an SQL-table than in a code file.

In the end I personally would prefer an external storage for easier migration, and simpler editing.

Answer (score 2):

Well, depends. For Adding and/or editing I would choose to store in a database. For performance, I would choose a php file - like a pair list of constant-text.

In any way, you should not use multi-dimensional array for this. When the page loads, you know for sure the language you will need. In this way, you can use a one-dimension array.
Instead of

```
$language['en']["hello"] = "Hello";
```

should be:

```
$language["hello"] = "Hello";
```

or

```
$language["hello"] = "Ahoj";
```

Because for hello you will take the appropriate language-text.

Comment: so I should use something like `if ($default_lang == "en"){$language['hello'] = 'hello';} if ($default_lang == "cz"){$language['hello'] = 'ahoj';}` ?

Comment: Not exactly. If for example you decide to keep it in the database, you will make a query like: SELECT * FROM LANGUAGES WHERE LANGUAGE='en'. This will give you all the english words. If you will keep them on the disk, you can create different files for each language: en_lang.php or cz_lang.php. Based on the customer language you can include the corresponding file.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a standard solution, as you're not the first person to need internationalization support :-)

If you're using the zend framework, take a look on Zend_Translate. They have different adapters, so you can use XML files, php arrays or gettext to save to text. http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.introduction.html

If it's a project without a framework, PECL has a great package for Internationalization:
http://pecl.php.net/package/intl

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, I would recommend defining the variables in PHP if only the programmer(s) are going to be editing those. If, however, you would like other people to edit them (through a web interface, perhaps), it would be better to place them in a database. This is slightly worse for performance, but will allow them to be edited by people who do not have access to the code (provided you make an interface for editing, of course).

Comment: And what about to store them in database and every time (or once 10 minutes) create (generate) php file with vars?

Comment: That's a possibility too. Generating the file every time wouldn't improve the performance at all (in fact, it would make it worse than simply accessing the variables from the database) so it hardly seems like a good idea. Generating a PHP file every 10 minutes, though, would probably give you much better performance than simply accessing the variables in the database. So, it would give you performance close to simply defining the variables in PHP, and the flexibility of having the variables in a database. It does have the downside of requiring cron or some other scheduling tool, though.

Answer (score 1):

I've used a cached database approach for performance reasons.

On some of our pages we could have 100 items that require translating and if each of those made separate calls to the database it would result in a huge overhead.

We quickly decided that we would not be translating more than a few thousand items and after some performance testing realised that the quickest way to do this is to fetch the entire (or a subset if you can) dictionary for the language required and for the page.  This dictionary is then loaded into a HashTable to make lookups quick.  Therefore only 1 DB access required per server request.

We tested it on a dictionary with 50,000 translation items and the performance was very good.

It also has the advantage that it can easily be tied to an Admin facility to allow users to edit the translations.

Answer (score 0):

I use standard linux gettext library, which is also provided in PHP.

In code:

```
_('ahoj');
```

Then I just edit the files messages_en.po for English translation and that's it. I made a Makefile to be able to compile the file fast and look for newly added phrases without a translation.

Answer (score 0):

When I was translating one of my sites to multi-language the database Idea quickly went out.

I know keeping translated data in variables seems novice. But it gave me the flexibility to use functions as well.

After all a site translation isn't the same as a dictionary there are situations when syntax is a problem. Hello ##username in English might be written ##username Hello in another language. Also global session variables like username, realname, etc. can be incorporated into the translation strings. Doing this with mysql would require to run a php search replace function on top of the translation data returned (##username hello, hello ##username) and make things more complicated and slow since every string would have to go through this function or at least an if statement.